# Sharepoint- Site Settings page design

Tags: sharepoint, designer

When i Customize  to design the Settings.aspx page,It looks same as Home Page What we Designed,One mistakes is the top navigation Menu's tab are not aligned as correct as Home Page,What my Mistake ,Please Anyone Help me..,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Branding is hard enough by itself, but the tabs always seem to give me issues as well. What usually helps me is to compare the two sections of rendered HTML (view source) for the tabs' sections. More often than not, there will a subtle difference that causes the misalignment.

Hope that helps.